# Live stream camera data from a server to a client

Tags: c++, qt, tcp

I'm working on a project, where I set up a server and a client, and the server sends webcam image to the client via TCPIP (for live stream on client).

For test purposes, I'm running both client and server on the same PC.

On the server side, using qcamera, I get webcam image, convert it to QByteArray, and send it to client.

However, I've noticed that upon sending an image data, the client cannot receive the data at one try. For example, if the server sends the QByteArray with length of 15000, the client receives data with length of 10000, 3000 and 2000, which adds up to 15000. (I'm using readyRead() signal and socket->readAll() function)

Thus, to live stream the webcam image on the client, I need a way to parse one camera image from the other. I've tried to add a terminator, such as ';', at the end of the QByteArray, but it seems that my webcam image array contains ';', '?', '*', etc., so I cannot use them as the terminator.

Is there any work around on this issue?

Comment: Why do you need a terminator if the data you send is always the same size?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found that the data is not always the same length. So, I figured that a terminator is needed.

Comment: How about sending the payload length before the array?

Comment: Yes, when sending binary data, sending the byte length before sending the bytes is generally preferred, as you usually can't guarantee the uniqueness of a single-byte terminator within the byte data

Comment: Swordfish, Remy Lebeau: thank you so much for your comments! Yeah, sending the length before the actual data would do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is Qt itself!

From qdoc:

```
  playlist = new QMediaPlaylist;
  playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/movie1.mp4"));
  playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/movie2.mp4"));
  playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/movie3.mp4"));
  playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);

  player = new QMediaPlayer;
  player->setPlaylist(playlist);

  videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
  player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
  videoWidget->show();

  player->play();
```

Also you can pass rtsp schema url to playlist